# Getting specific items from binary files with an index in python

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, pytorch

I'm using pytorch but getting trouble with reading large datasets. Considering the size of data, it is necessary to save them as files.

Rather than preprocessing data into batches and save them as files respectively, I'm seeking for a method that can read specific parts of only one or a few binary files, with an index file (if necessary) indicating the corresponding file and positions for seeking.

For example, supposing a dataset file containing a lot of images (maybe with different size), and an index file indicating the start position and the end position of each image. A dict-like or list-like container  `data` is initialized with the index file. When I want to read the third image, I can simply use `data[2]` and it can jump to the specific position fast and return what I want.

Is there an existing method that can handle it well? As far as I know, SQL or pandas might be a possible solution for **fixed field length** data, but I don't know if they can handle varient filed length and binary data.

Comment: take a look to HDF5 format?

Comment: @Corralien Thanks! The H5PY module really works!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `DataLoader` class. The class is used to read data from external sources (databases, data streams, file storage, etc.). You will need to implement `__len__()` and `__getitem__()` methods.

To allow the use of an index file that will help you to load the data from the custom dataset, you can use `IterableDataset`.

You can find more information in the [pytorch manuals](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) related to data handling, as well as you can see some of the following examples:

- [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel)
- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html
- https://medium.com/speechmatics/how-to-build-a-streaming-dataloader-with-pytorch-a66dd891d9dd

So in your case, you will implement the logic for reading the binary file (or the slice of the binary file) in the `__getitem__()` in the `DataLoader`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! IterableDataset is very useful for me. The HDF5 format is the best solution and it worths a try to combine HDF5 with IterableDataset.